# Android - dataSnapshot.getValue() returns null on second call (but not first)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to loop through each index of the "People" child to set the value of the snapshot to a provider within an adapter. When the user looks at the adapter, they can see the persons name, age, hair color, and eye color.

[**My Firebase Database Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlHCN.png) 
*(linked since I can't embed images yet)*

**My Function**

```
public void getInfo() {


 ValueEventListener profileListener = new ValueEventListener() {


    @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


       totalPeople = dataSnapshot.child("People").getChildrenCount();            


       for (int personIndex = 0; personIndex < totalPeople; personIndex++){


          String name =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("name").getValue().toString();


          String age =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("age").getValue().toString();


          String hairColor =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("hairColor").getValue().toString();


          String eyeColor =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("eyeColor").getValue().toString();


          PersonProvider personProvider = new PersonProvider(name, age, hairColor, eyeColor);

          personActivityAdapter.add(personProvider);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fetching data from firebase failed");
    }
 }; 

 myRef.child("users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(profileListener);
}
```

**Error**

```
06-06 11:38:21.900 31357-31357/com.RentRedi.RentRedi2 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.RentRedi.RentRedi2.VehicleActivity$10.onDataChange(VehicleActivity.java:380)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZV(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

**Attempts**

When I change:

```
String name =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("name").getValue().toString();
```

to:

```
String name =  dataSnapshot.child("People").child(String.valueOf(personIndex)).child("name").toString();
```

it does return the whole dataSnapshot as a string, with all of its keys and values. However, when I add `.getValue()` I get a null pointer exception after personIndex is hit the first time.

**Note:** I also switched the order of the the snapshots (such as, put `age` first, `hairColor` first, or `eyeColor` first. It always gets the value of the first one but crashes on the second, stating that the value is null.

**Why is it returning null on the second call, but not the first, no matter which dataSnapshot child I put first?**

Comment: Yes, it has sub-nodes with sequential indexes. I have added a link to the image of my firebase database at the top of the post.

Comment: rename `people` to `People` and try

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I renamed `people` to `People` but the same error occurs